# Bootstrap grid outisde the div container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I am trying to put 2 `input` inside a bootstrap grid and they are outside the div container, to the left or the right side.

And yet, the code looks ok:

```
<div style="max-width:500px;margin:auto;">
    <div style="background-color:red;">
      Test!
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;">
            <input name="InputName" type="text" width="100%" placeholder="Your name" style="width:100%;margin: 0; border-radius:0;border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);height: 50px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
            <input name="InputEmail" type="text" width="100%" placeholder="Your email" style="width:100%;border-radius:0;border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);border-left:0;height: 50px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/defacta/skvs9krd/), the red background of the first `col-sm-6` is outside the div container to the left, and the yellow background of the second `col-sm-6` is outside the div container to the right.

Why ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

and also styles related to your col-sm

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Comment: Yes I see, it's because the default Bootstrap margin and padding of the grid system.
https://jsfiddle.net/defacta/wkbxwdru/
Thanks :)

Comment: No problem :). Can you vote for my post? I need reputation to chat related to my question. Thanks!